# Maven: Including external JAR in POM

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml, dspace

I know questions like this have been asked and answered before, and have taken the time to read those threads, but somehow they won't help me. I have locally added own Java code to the [DSpace](http://www.dspace.org) software, and my code depends on another library, so I'll have to include this library (JAR) into the `<dependencies>` section of the POM, right? This is what my entry looks like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.mannheim.ids</groupId>
        <artifactId>pid</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <systemPath>/absolute/path/to/jar/pid-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

This does not help but results in a Compile Error - the relevant classes cannot be found. I have also tried `mvn install:install-file -Dfile...`, which tells me everything is fine with the jar (BUILD SUCCESS), but the subsequent `mvn package` fails with the usual error.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Huh... a previous comment here just disappeared suggesting to use the `compile` scope instead of `system`.

Wouldn't this mean that the other library would have to be in a repository? Sorry if I have been unclear about this, I only have a local copy of that JAR. Also, the `systemPath` element is only allowed with a `system` scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the artifact as usual after using `mvn install:install`.

If that command returned Build successful you should be able to use this in your pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.mannheim.ids</groupId>
        <artifactId>pid</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven will find it like it would find any jar in your local repository.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, `mvn install:install` (without the file specification etc.) gave me an error which I do not understand - can you help?


    [INFO] [install:install {execution: default-cli}]
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------      
    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact`

Comment: Could you copy/paste the exact command you typed ? Please refer to the usage documentation here : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html. Not all arguments are mandatory but you need a least to specify the following `mvn -X install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/mly/jar -DgroupId=j<groupname> -DartifactId=<artifactname> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar`. Of course you then need to specify the same artifactId, groupId and version in your pom.

Comment: This is my exact command:
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/joachim/workspace/DSpace3/pid-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=de.mannheim.ids -DartifactId=pid -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar`

This command returns BUILD SUCCESSFUL, and the POM entry looks just like the one you posted in your answer.

Comment: Wait - the JAR that I want to add depends on yet other libraries. Do I have to add those to the repository/POM too? Besides that, I have verified that the JAR I need is actually inside the local repo, so everything looking good here.

Comment: When you add a Jar manually you can either upload a pom.xml (with -DpomFile) file listing its dependencies or use it as such. In the latter case, transitive dependencies will not be retrieved since maven would have no information about it. I do not advise that, uploading a pom file is the way to go but if you need to do it that way you will have to list dependencies explicitly.